# how to convert date in d-m-y format to y-m-d format using php

Tags: php, date

```
$date = 21/10/2015
```

And I want the date in `2015-10-21` (`y-m-d`) format.

I tried:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

But it only works for dates less than 12.

Comment: Its working in less than 12 because its treating 21 as month. mm/dd/yyyy is a valid format. dd/mm/yyyy is invalid. Explode like `$dates = explode('/', $date);` and then use mktime like `$date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $dates[1], $dates[0], $dates[2]));`

Comment: [Valid date formats for strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)... note the differences between using `/` and `-` as separators